# electroplating with different electrode and electrolyte

Tags: electroplating

I wanted to make a school project on galvanic
 cells and I would like to know of I can make electroplating with electrolyte of $\ce{NaCl}$ to plate let's say a spoon with the sodium from the salt but with out sodium anode.
my view is that electroplating works when the positively charged $\ce{Na+}$ ions are reduced to $\ce{Na}$ at the cathode so why do we need the cathode to be sodium as long as it can reduce the sodium ions?

Comment: You can, but you need to do it in molten salt. Google Down's Process. Best avoided for school projects!

Answer (score 4):

Before you start with your experiments, you might want to read about the concept of a [standard electrode potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential) and have a look at some [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)), particulary for hydrogen, sodium and chlorine.

## Can I electrolyze an aqueous solution of sodium chloride?

> **Yes you can - but you'll be surprised!**
>  That is, unless you you have checked and understood the data in the link given above.
>
>  You would then realize that instead of $\ce{Na+}$, protons will be reduced at the cathode while chlorine will be formed by anodic oxidation of $\ce{Cl-}$.
>
>  **In short: No sodium metal will be formed here.**

## Can I produce sodium metal by electrolysis of sodium chloride?

> **Yes, you can - in principle!**
>
>  But you probably can't in a school project. Electrolysis requires that your medium is electrically conductive. An aqueous $\ce{NaCl}$ solution is, but that won't help you. A block of solid sodium chloride, on the other hand is a lousy conductor. The situation changes dramatically if you can manage to melt the salt. Molten sodium chloride has a high electrical conductivity. The downside is the melting point of $\ce{NaCl}$ - it is around 800 °C. You could add some calcium chloride to lower the melting point of the mixture to ~ 500 °C, but that's still a lot. Probably a bit too hot for a school project.
>
>  **So, does anybody use this sh*t?**
>
>    Yes, this is the established way to produce sodium metal using a special setup known as the [Downs cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downs_cell). But remember, this is in industry, and not suitable for a school project ;-)
>
>  **But I could use a big spoon as an electrode and electroplate it?**
>
>  No, sorry! Under the conditions of the industrial electrolysis of molten sodium chloride, sodium is formed. But the melting point of sodium metal is just ~ 98 °C. It is a liquid with a lower density than the molten sodium chloride. The liquid sodium metal is collected above the (iron) cathode.

In summary, I suggest that you rethink your school project ;-)